# add button to uitextfield

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

When I click inside text box, How can I add plus button to UITextField as shown in the following screen? When this button is clicked it would launch iPhone contact application. I would very much appreciate any code example. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use following  method for add `UIButton`

```
[self.txtField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (BOOL) textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIButton *btnColor = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnColor addTarget:self action:@selector(btnColorPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnColor.frame = CGRectMake(self.txtTag.bounds.size.width - 50, 5, 25, 25);
    [btnColor setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PaintPickerButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.txtTag addSubview:btnColor];

    return YES;
}
```

**Or Write**

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    // self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 35, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 250);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    UIButton *btnColor = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnColor addTarget:self action:@selector(btnColorPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnColor.frame = CGRectMake(150, 5, 25, 25);
    [btnColor setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PaintPickerButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.txtField addSubview:btnColor];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: why using  self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 35, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 250);

Comment: @pengwang- sory i copy code from my project so this line i foragt to remove :)

Comment: Manually adding your own UIButton is not acceptable, when the text field becomes active the button will be sent to the back and not be tappable! Best solution is to use the `rightView` property

Answer (score 9):

Following code use for adding button in UITextField.

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 120, 160, 40)];
    txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txt.placeholder = @"Enter or Mobile Number";
    [txt setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"crossImg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -16, 0, 0);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clearText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    txt.rightView = button;
    txt.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [self.view addSubview:txt];
}

-(IBAction)clearText:(id)sender{

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the below code for this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if(textField == yourFirstTextField)
  {
      UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourActionHere) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
      textField.rightView = addButton;
  }
}
```

You can use the above method if you added the field in IB.

If you are created it through code, you need to add the below code when creating:

```
UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourActionHere) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
textField.rightView = addButton;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `rightView` property of `UITextField`.
In `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` delegate create button with action you want & set to `rightView`.
And in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` set nil to `rightView`

Answer (score 1):

you can also go for custom view ant then add sub view to it. then you hide it. it will be visible only when the user taps it

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.locationName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"goButtonIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(goButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.locationName.rightView = button;
    self.locationName.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;
```

and then call this method:

```
-(IBAction)goButtonClicked:(id)sender{

}
```

self.locationName   -------> UITextField Reference (in ViewDidload you can write this code)